# iOS Marketplace payments, using PayPal for User to User Payment incl. comission

Tags: ios, mobile, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, marketplace

We would like to create a marketplace app in iOS where the user makes a PayPal payment to the vendors paypal account and we receive a small commission.

We have three (possibly basic) questions where we struggle to make sense of what exactly paypal adaptive payments offers (and if this is the right solution).

1. Is PayPal adaptive Payments the correct (or at least a feasible) solution for this purpose?
2. What happens to the PayPal fee (normally 30c + 2.8%) and who pays this? Is this charged to the vendor? Obviously we couldn't pay a 30c fee on the commission (as this would erode the commission).
3. Are there any other restrictions we should keep in mind? I know there are credit card regulations in place that makes paying into a credit card very restrictive, but I was of the believe that payments between two paypal accounts were ok?

The way I imagine it is that the buyer in our app would be redirected to a PayPal in-lay where after entering there PayPal details the payment (and commission payment) processes are started simultaneously.

Thank you so much for your help in advance. Apologies if these are obvious (to the PayPal aficionado) but we are very much trying to asses the scope before working our way into the PayPal SDK.